# How to add a movieclip to the stage then make it move down?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making a game where i want to spawn zombies then make them move down the screen. I also want to have multiple on the screen at once. I have tried multiple ways now but none of them have worked.

Here is my code

```
if ((zombie == 1)||(zombie == 3)||(zombie == 5)||(zombie == 7))
{
    var Z = new Z;
    Z.x = 403.25;
    Z.y = -86.9;
    Z.rotation = 90;
    addChild(Z)
    zombie += 1;
}

//Functions
function startzombie(event)
{
    trace("start zombies")
    zombie = 1;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,zombiemove) 
}
function zombiemove(event:Event)
{
    Z.y += 1;
}
```

Z is the zombie

Comment: If `Z` is the zombie, what is `zombie`?
When you create your new instance of `Z` (assuming `Z` is a class), you should write something more like `var newZombie:Z = new Z();`, i.e. don't forget the parenthesis, specify the type of your new instance and name your new instance with a name different from the name of your class.
Also, showing the code of your `Z` class could help you having a good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an Array that will hold references to your zombie instances, instead of a single variable of class Zombie, whatever it is name. Then, in the part of code that moves zombies, you iterate through that array and advance all zombies in there. Also you need to check if some zombies are already defunct so that you need to remove them from screen and from array, and act accordingly.

```
var za:Array; // initialize elsewhere
....
function addZombie():void {
    var z:Zombie=new Zombie();
    z.x=Math.random()*600; // position that zombie
    z.y=-20; // somewhere
    addChild(z);
    za.push(z);
}
function advanceZombies():void {
    for (var i:int=za.length-1;i>=0;i--) za[i].walkABit();
}
```

You call a method in Zombie class specially designed for moving the zombie. They can be say stunned or slowed so that this move might not occur, and it's of no deal to your main class to control each and every zombie's alterable behavior, this is what's named "black box concept". You say "move", they move if they are able.